# Uploading JSON data to line Chart.JS using local host server

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js, localhost

Below is my JS code for uploading the data:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:3000/AUDcotdata";
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(data);
        var AUDL = data.LONGDEALERINTERMEDIARY;
        var AUDS = data.SHORTDEALERINTERMEDIARY
    }
    const AUDlinecharttop = document.getElementById('fxlinecharttopAUD').getContext('2d');
    const AUDlinechart1 = new Chart(AUDlinecharttop, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7','8','9','10'] ,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Short",
                data: AUDS,
                backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
                borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
                borderWidth: 4,
            },
            { label: "Long" ,
                data: AUDL,
                backgroundColor: ['rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'],
                borderColor: ['rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'],
                borderWidth: 4
            }],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: "true",
            plugins: {
                title: {
                    color: "white",
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Positions (AUD)',
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    color: "white"
                }
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            elements: {
                line: {
                    fill: true,
                    tension: 0.2
                }
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    ticks: {
                        color: "white"
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
                x: {
                    ticks: {
                        color: "white"
                    },
                    grid: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The chart shows up with the labels and the X axis (as it's manually done). But the data does not show as there seems to be an issue getting the data from the JSON file. Below is the data inside the json:

```
[
  {
    "LONGDEALERINTERMEDIARY": [
      {
        "0": 57387,
        "1": 71459,
        "2": 63223,
        "3": 66892,
        "4": 74976,
        "5": 74008,
        "6": 62787,
        "7": 59250,
        "8": 58953,
        "9": 42261
      }
    ],
    "SHORTDEALERINTERMEDIARY": [
      {
        "0": 3346,
        "1": 3205,
        "2": 3109,
        "3": 3482,
        "4": 4591,
        "5": 4228,
        "6": 3998,
        "7": 3351,
        "8": 5525,
        "9": 6516
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I don't think the way I'm uploading it is correct, any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `AUDL` and `AUDS` need to be arrays. What you're providing is an object.

Comment: okay thanks, do you have an idea how I can adjust them into arrays?

Comment: Try `var AUDL = Object.values(data.LONGDEALERINTERMEDIARY)` and the same for `AUDS`

Comment: Just tried that and this is the erorr i get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: That would mean `data.LONGDEALERINTERMEDIARY` returned `undefined`. I just noticed that the json root is an array as well as `LONGDEALERINTERMEDIARY`. If you are correctly fetching the json you've shown here, then you can only access the actual entries using `data[0].LONGDEALERINTERMEDIARY[0]`.

Comment: Basically, `Object.values()` ignores the keys and gets all the values from an object. `{ "0": 1000, "1": 2000 }` would become `[ 1000, 2000 ]`. Make sure you're passing the final object in json to `Object.values()` and try console logging `AUDL` and `AUDS` afterwards as well. Everything should be fine once you just have the correct values as arrays.